# Select results that contains part of string mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for a method to get rows that are more similar with inserted string

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE column have part of '$search_string';
```

In other words if search string is **My name is TOM** and in the column I have

```
COLUMN
---------------
My name is Sara

My name is Jack

My dog is white

---------------
```

results must be:

all rows that contains **My name is**, because they are most similar to `$search_string`.

I've tried to use `LIKE` operator with phrase splatted in words, but I'm not obtaining the result that I want, any ideas?

Comment: See about FULLTEXT indexes - but be wary of situations where the search string matches more than 50% of the rows.

Comment: You may parse the search string to separate words (using JSON_TABLE, for example), count the amount of words found in each separate value, and return the values where this amount is not less than some value (for example, above a half of total words amount).

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE COLUMN LIKE 'My name is %'
```

?

UPDATED

```
"SELECT * FROM db WHERE COLUMN LIKE '%$search%'"
```

Comment: I don't know what will be the search string. This was only an example.

Comment: @Victor,  okej, i got it, please try updated version of my unswer :) don't forget to use double quotes for query, that's how you can parse your variable

Comment: I've already tried that. But if $search is "My name is TOM" as in example, i've got nothing as result. :(

Comment: yes, because you are searching for %My name is TOM% instead, you have in database other values. Well in that case you need to look into full text search: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-full-text-search-functions.php#:~:text=Full%2DText%20Search%20in%20MySQL,based%20columns%20in%20the%20table.